# Can the number of partitions of a Kafka topic be decreased?

Tags: apache-kafka

I didn't think it was possible to alter the number of topics for a partition, however I then found [this documentation page](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka/operations-tools/topic-operations.html#increase-partitions-for-a-topic).

There is a section with the title *Increase Partitions for a Topic*, which suggests that the number of partitions can only be *increased* and not *decreased*. Is this the case?

If the number of partitions was *decreased* what would happen?

- Is this a disallowed operation?
- Would data be deleted? (I would assume this doesn't happen, but I don't know for sure.)
- Would existing data be re-distributed from the deleted topics to the other topics, or perhaps something else?

Obviously - the above question(s) become irrelevant if this is a disallowed operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitions indeed cannot be decreased. You should expect an error message if you try to perform such operations.

More specifically, data cannot directly be "moved" from partition N to N-1, and modifying partitions doesn't affect other topics, so there's no data movement between topics